# textarea value update without delete the previous Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, jquery-events

what I'm trying to do to insert new data in text area without effect the previous one:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="data" name="data">
roma is the most visit
</textarea>

  $("#data").val('new line without delete the previous one ');
```

what I expect:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="data" name="data">
roma is the most visit
new line without delete the previous one 
</textarea>
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.append()` instead of `.val()` ([doc](https://api.jquery.com/append/)):

```js
$("#data").append('new line without delete the previous one ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="data" name="data">
roma is the most visit
</textarea>
```